# Using icpc with the gnu libstdc++in a nonstandard location

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++, icc

I'm trying to use icpc with c++11 features, however I need a c++11 stdlib, which intel doesn't provide.

I'm running as a user on RHEL 6, so the systems libstdc++ is out of date.  There is a newer version installed, but it is in a non-standard location.

How do I link to a gcc std library in a non-standard location?  What flags do I use?

Comment: Hmm. It uses the system library just fine here (ICC 13.0.0 20120731). I don't have to specify anything special. Did you actually enable C++-11 mode? (`-std=c++11` compiler flag.)

Comment: The problem is that the system standard library is old (gcc 4.0 maybe). I need to link to a version of the c++ std library in a different version of GCC, which is in a different location.

Comment: Ah, OK. Sorry though, no idea how that is done. I installed ICC through the package manager and never dealt with that stuff.

Comment: I have a similar issue: icpc 10 falls over because it uses gcc4.7.0 std library headers (which implement delegating constructors, which icpc doesn't understand).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ICC, but have you tried the usual `-I` and `-L` options for headers and libraries, respectively?

I would try running the newer `g++` with the `-v` flag which will tell you all the directories it searches for its headers and libraries, then tell ICC to look in those same paths.

I'm pretty sure RHEL6 doesn't come with GCC 4.0, since RHEL5 comes with GCC 4.1!  I think it's 4.4 on RHEL6, if memory serves correctly, which does support some C++11 features, but you might need to define `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` if ICC doesn't define that when you use `-std=c++11`.

Comment: so, -I and -L are for includes and library directories for normal libs... but isn't stdc++ different?

Comment: no, its headers are scattered across a few dirs, but that's all